# Measure given by an integral

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Find $\mu( \mathbb Q \cap [0,1] )$ and $\mu( \mathbb Q \cup [0,1] )$, where $\mathcal L(\mathbb R)$ is the Lebesgue sigma algebra and the function $\mu: \mathcal L(\mathbb{R})\to [0,\infty]$ maps $A \mapsto \int_{A} x^2  \ d \lambda(x)$.

Just how can I plug the sets in the integral? Thanks

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two useful facts:

- If $A$ is a set of measure zero and $f$ is any measurable function, then
  $ \int_A f \ d\lambda = 0.$
- If $A = [a,b]$ is an interval and $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $\int_A f \ d\lambda$ is equal to the Riemann integral of $f$ over $[a,b]$.

Using the first fact, it should be possible to solve the case $A = \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$ immediately.

For $A = \mathbb Q \cup [0,1]$, we could split $A$ into two disjoint subsets:
$$ A = A_1 \cup A_2,$$ $$ {\rm with \ \ } A_1 = [0,1] {\rm \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ } A_2 = \mathbb Q \cap \left( (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)\right).$$
Now observe that $A_1$ is an interval and $A_2$ is of measure zero...

Comment: So it is just the integral from 0 to 1 from that integral?

Comment: Yes, for the second one.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.